# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in SchedulesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attr-accessor

im trying to declare some virtual attributes that will be used to combine date and time together given me date time, though i keep getting the following error. as you can see from the code examples below, how im setting the attributes, and what information im passing through to them.

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in SchedulesController#create

{"utf8"=>"✓",


"authenticity_token"=>"j4V6DAqK5U/+ZGaSKDlrEoOBqXu3pEq/FM51ingi2sg=",
 "schedule"=>{"event"=>"1",
 "result_id"=>"",
 "date"=>"04/11/2012",
 "arrival_time"=>"08:00 PM",
 "time"=>"08:00 PM",
 "duration"=>"1800",
 "location_id"=>"11",
 "selected_players"=>["",
 "41",
 "38"],
 "team_id"=>"1",
 "opponent_id"=>"1",
 "home_or_away"=>"Home"},
 "commit"=>"Save Event"}
```

controller

```
    # POST /schedules
  # POST /schedules.json
  def create
    params[:schedule].delete(:date)
    params[:schedule].delete(:time)
    @user = User.find(current_user)

    @players = User.where(:team_id => current_user[:team_id]).all
    params[:schedule][:selected_players].compact
    #params[:schedule][:selected_players].reject!{|selected_players| selected_players==""}
    #@availabilities = @user.availabilities.create(:unique_id => params[:schedule][:id])

    @schedule = Schedule.new(params[:schedule])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @schedule.save
        #Notifier.event_added(@user,@schedule).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to(schedules_url,
                                  :notice => "#{event_display_c(@schedule.event)} vs #{@schedule.opponent.name} was successfully created.") }
        format.json { render :json => @schedule, :status => :created, :location => @schedule }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @schedule.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

model

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :opponent
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :result
  has_many :availabilities, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :location_id, :user_id, :opponent_id, :datetime, :score_for, :score_against, :event,
                  :team_id, :home_or_away, :arrival_time, :duration, :selected_players, :result_id

  attr_accessor :date, :time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this out for myself, just added the fields in the database in the end

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting a MassAssignmentSecurity error because you are passing the virtual attributes `time` and `date` into `Schedule.new` when you instantiate the new schedule, and since they are not in the list of whitelisted attributes, Rails assumes they are attributes that should not be mass assigned. You should delete them from `params` before initiating the new schedule, and then (if needed) set the corresponding instance variables directly:

```
def create
  date = params[:schedule].delete(:date)
  time = params[:schedule].delete(:time)
  @schedule = Schedule.new(params[:schedule])
  @schedule.date = date
  @schedule.time = time
  ...
```

If you want to then set `datetime` from `date` and `time` when the model is saved, you should create an `before_save` callback to do that (maybe you already have).

Comment: `date` and `time`? They are attr_accessors in the code the OP posted.

Comment: Is it possible the error is about the `Availability` model and not the `Schedule` model? In the line `@availabilities = @user.availabilities.create(:schedule_id => params[:schedule][:id])` you assign `schedule_id` to a newly-created record, which could raise a mass assignment error if `schedule_id` is not in the list of `attr_accessible` for the `Availability` model.

Comment: Can you confirm which line in the create action is causing the error? I've tested similar code and I think my original answer is correct, I get the mass assignment error when I try to create the new instance. If the fix above is not working, then you need to narrow down what attribute is causing it.

Comment: Also can you post your model schema for `Schedule`?

Comment: removed @availabilities same issue the error still states `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in SchedulesController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: date, time`

Comment: Yes so the problem is with the assignment to `Schedule.new`. It doesn't make sense that it's raising the error if you're deleting `date` and `time` from the hash. Are you sure your code is exactly in the order above? Try adding a `puts params` line between the `date` and `time` delete lines and the `Schedule.new` line to make sure they're not there.

Comment: Sorry, I really can't see anything else from the code you've shown here. It should delete those attributes from `params[:schedule]` so it doesn't make sense to me that the mass assignment error is still coming up. What if you put a `puts params[:schedule]` right before the `Schedule.new` line? If you see a `date` or `time` there then that's the cause. If not, one other possibility: are you overriding `new` in your `Schedule` model? Or do you have any other callbacks that would be called before `new`? I'm grasping for straws here.

Comment: this doesnt make sense, ive stripped it back to bare min, this is so stupid you should be able to make virtual form elements on fly without a hassle

Comment: Sorry, you've lost my sympathy. Figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters which are not being made acessible. Then do this:

```
date = params[:schedule]
@schedule = Schedule.new(params[:schedule]) do |schedule|
  schedule.date = date
  ...
end
```

alternatively, you can set the mass-assignment rules to non-strict:

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :logger
```

and instead of having these exceptions, the filtered attributes will just be logged. then you can do this:

```
@schedule = Schedule.new(params[:schedule]) do |schedule|
  schedule = params[:schedule][:date]
  ...
end
```